How do I close a phantom window that is leftover from compiz (I think?)
I am running the latest version of Compiz from Ubuntu launchpad with Mate. Sometimes when I right-click on a title bar, it leaves a phantom window that you can see below.
I have tried restarting compiz or switching to a different window manager (completely closing compiz), but it does not go away. I have tried wmctrl -l to list windows, and while it maybe a real window that X is rendering, wmctrl -l does not list it because (presumably) it is not a top level window.
Interestingly, I can change the shadow size in the Compiz “decoration settings”, which leads me to believe that this is a real window and not a drawing glitch.
Also, it is more than just a glitch because it is impossible to click inside the shadowed box.  I can click anywhere outside the box, but clicks in the box are not ignored by all applications.
Of course an actual solution to fix the problem is preferred, but please add comments with any suggestions to help troubleshoot as well. Here are some XY problem questions to which I do not have an answer that may help troubleshoot the issue:

Is there a way to list all X windows, not just top level WM windows?
Is there a way to run a program that allows me to click on the phantom window and get a "window ID" to figure out what it is?



I was able to use the Compiz configuration settings manager (ccsm) "Window decoration-> Decoration Windows-> +" button to "grab" the phantom windoww: It told me that the title was gtk-window-decorator.
So, restarted the decorator and it worked!
~]$ ps ax|grep decor
   4323 ?        Ssl  114:30 gtk-window-decorator
3180535 pts/28   S+     0:00 grep --color=auto decor
~]$ kill 4323
~]$ gtk-window-decorator & 
[1] 3180587
~]$ disown

